# Classes in nav only work with inspecting element in firefox

Tags: html, css, firefox, navbar, nav

I want to code a navigation bar for my website. It should support a mobile and a desktop view. Now I want to add a div in nav and it doesn't work, but when I analyse it with inspecting element in firefox and refresh the site it works. Can anyone help me?

Here is a code-snippet of the nav:

```css
/* Here is the css declaration of the drop class: */

.drop {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
}
```

```html
<nav class="nav" id='navigation'>
  <ul style="font: normal 14px Tauri, serif ">


    <li style="float: left; border: none ">
      <a href='index.php'>test</a>
    </li>


    <button class="drop"></button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually there is a "nav" but it got no height.
I did a Fiddle where I added some height and a background color, also removing margin to the body, check this out!

https://jsfiddle.net/tu9rh3sg/

This for the HTML (I've just closed the nav):

```
 <nav class="nav" id='navigation'>
  <ul style="font: normal 14px Tauri, serif ">


    <li style="float: left; border: none ">
      <a href='index.php'>test</a>
    </li>


    <button class="drop"></button>
    </nav>
```

And this for the CSS (height + background-color+margin);

```
    .drop {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
}
.nav {
  background-color: black;
  height: 50px;
}
body {
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-top: -14px;
}
```

Tell me if it help ! ☻